# Can't Edit Sources in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In DevTools, it seems that there are some javascript files that can be edited and others that are "locked," meaning I can't place my cursor inside the file or type anything. What is the reason for this and how can I actually edit these files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the file has been prettified (i.e. de-minified) Chrome will not allow you to edit the file. Are you attempting to edit a prettified minified file? Also, javascript in an embedded in a PHP or HTML file will remain read-only.

Comment: Correct. I am attempting to edit a prettified minified file. I didn't believe that would matter but it appears that you are correct. I did find a suggestion elsewhere to prettify, copy and paste the code into another editor, then make your changes there, and finally paste and save back in DevTools.

Comment: In my case its embedded in HTML file. Can't edit. :/